# Can I always exclude specific recipient from Reply All?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have mails send to me and some other persons by automated system with non-working e-mail address, and frequently I have to reply all to that message and then manually exclude that non-working mail from recipients list. That non-working mail address never changes, can I set outlook to exclude that mail every time ?

Comment: I would tend to doubt it, as reply all is in effect telling outlook that you want to send a message to this person, though you don't actually want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I wrote little outlook 2010 addin to add this functionality, [here](http://www.antoniob.com/outlook-2010-addin-exclude-no-reply.html) is the code. If there is interest I will put binaries of that addin also.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this answer would require scripting in VBA. You might want to look at [this programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697060/change-item-to-value-in-outlook-when-sending-a-message-using-vba) for insights on altering the recipient list of outgoing mail.

Answer (score -2):

I guess I didn't read it all the way so I though you were looking for something else, but now that I read it and understood it fully I think Myrddin Emrys is offeres the only solution here...

the other way would be to do it on server side, using some rules it's possible to do alot more then outlook rules, i'm not sure if wherever your email is hosting is provides you this sort of functionality... just an example (this may not be what you have, so you'd need to do more research on  your end) there are few more but it all depends what is installed and available to you as a user.

[maildrop - mail delivery agent with filtering abilities](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/)

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: How is this applicable?

Comment: There is no rule I'm aware of that will edit the To or CC field of an outgoing message to clear a particular address. This answer does not appear to address the question.

Comment: maildrop can do it! i had few custom rules on my server